# How to iterate over base objects that is a certain derived class

Tags: c++

Lets say I have implemented the following classes

```
class A
{
   public:
      virtual void printA() 
      { 
         cout << "Hi from A!" << endl; 
      }
};

class B : public A
{  
   public:
      virtual void printB() 
      { 
         cout << "Hi from B!" << endl; 
      }
};

class C : public B
{
   public:
      void printC() 
      { 
         cout << "Hi from C!" << endl; 
      }
};
```

Lets also say I have created a `std::vector<A *> vec` that contains random amount of objects instantiated from A, B, and C. Now lets say I am forced to iterate through all the objects in `vec` but only call objects that have the `printC()` method (i.e `C` instances). What is the best way to do this?

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<A *> vec;

    ....
    // insert random objects from both A, B and C into vec
    ....

    for(vector<A *>::iterator x = vec.begin();
        x != vec.end();
        x++)
    {
       if(dynamic_cast<C *>(*x) != 0)   // 1. is this OK?
         (*x)->printC();
       else
         (*x)->printA();                // 2. is this also OK?

    }
}
```

1. Is 1 Ok? And if so is this the best practice?
2. Also will 2 cause problems in the case of C instances?

Maybe these are stupid questions, but Im quite new to C++ and how polymorphism works in C++ is very strange to me. Thanks

Comment: What is `i`, I don't see it defined.

Comment: This won't compile. Because `printC()` is not a member function of `A`. Give a better example

Comment: Plus you have to make `print()` public.

Comment: Plus you have to have virtual destructors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 won't work, since `*x` has type `A*`, and `A` doesn't have a `printC` member. It should be:

```
if (C * c = dynamic_cast<C *>(*x)) {
    c->printC();
}
```

2 is fine, but doesn't match your description; you say you want to "only call objects that have the `printC()` method", while this calls `printA()` on the other objects.

This does seem like an odd design though; you'd usually define a single virtual function, implemented by each class to do the right thing for that class, then call that unconditionally for everything.

Answer (score 3):

I think you mean the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


int main() 
{
    class A
    {
    public: 
        virtual ~A() = default;
        virtual void print() const 
        { 
            std::cout << "Hi from A!" << std::endl; 
        }
    };

    class B : public A
    {  
    public: 
        void print() const
        { 
            std::cout << "Hi from B!" << std::endl;
        }
    };

    class C : public B
    {
    public:
        void print() const 
        { 
            std::cout << "Hi from C!" << std::endl; 
        }
    };

    std::vector<A *> v = { new A(), new B(), new C() };

    for ( A *p : v ) p->print();

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
Hi from A!
Hi from B!
Hi from C!
```